# Heroku Force Clear Varnish Cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Is it possible to force Heroku to clear out the Varnish cache from within an application (i.e. without pushing a new repository)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though [this Heroku mailing list message](http://www.mail-archive.com/heroku@googlegroups.com/msg04359.html) is a year old, I haven't found anything to contradict it.

> No, there's no official way to
>   manually expire your cache on Varnish.
>   If you need more control over your
>   cache (ie setting when it expires is
>   not enough) I'd recommend using
>   Memcache instead.

I doubt this has changed. Since Varnish is run outside the context of the Rails app, there probably isn't a `Varnish` class or anything like that, so no method that would purge the cache. Looks like you're on your own.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I'll need some sort of combination of Memcache and Varnish.