# How to flush Varnish cache on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, memcached, varnish

Is there a way to force a flush (purge) of the varnish cache on heroku? After `git push heroku master` my old (and wrong) cache is still in place.

**UPDATE :** I tried to set varnish = 0 then commit & push heroku +master again

```
-      response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=604800'
+      response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=0'
```

but doesn't help ...

**UPDATE :** I tried an `heroku restart` but doesn't help ...

**UPDATE :** Until now seems there's no official way to manually expire your Varnish cache on Heroku ( see the post [heroku-force-clear-varnish-cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182754/heroku-force-clear-varnish-cache) ). I just open an issue on Heroku support, let see what they'll say ...

Comment: Is it actually stale or is your browser cache still caching it? git push clears varnish (if you're not on cedar, which doesn't have varnish) but you'll probably still need to tell the browser to pull fresh.

Comment: it seems my local cache is clean (firefox is not caching)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently things went ok by itself after the last `heroku restart` ( notice, I already did the same several times without success ), notice X-Varnish num on the following query:

**BEFORE RESTART:**

lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/gitwatcher$ curl -I PURGE http://gitwatcher.com/
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'PURGE'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 26 May 2012 19:16:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Ua-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Etag: "f5a232e0193cfc6ad55c7b19033552b5"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Set-Cookie: _rails3-mongoid-omniauth-simple_session=BAh7B0kiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRkkiJTk0YTk3YTFlYWU5ZjMwYmE4M2Y3MzBlZGE5NWE5ZTYzBjsAVEkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMTFpL0pKbHl0OFRLYnpoZFJCbmlrKytOUmRKWi9Kd0MxdExPektUVTErOUk9BjsARg%3D%3D--826c4f58013b8a28da1544ab455ac928e1d8c961; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Request-Id: bd82e473e163a47f57440e351d2757ce
X-Runtime: 0.021009
X-Rack-Cache: stale, invalid
Content-Length: 8302
Accept-Ranges: bytes
**X-Varnish: 197775566**
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish

**AFTER RESTART**

lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/gitwatcher$ curl -I PURGE http://gitwatcher.com/
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'PURGE'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 26 May 2012 19:18:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Ua-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Etag: "495098767d9e77dc52081d8de3f4b27e"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Set-Cookie: _rails3-mongoid-omniauth-simple_session=BAh7B0kiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRkkiJWRkNTZiZDQ1YmY5YzhjM2Y3MTRiNmEwZjg4Y2YyMGE1BjsAVEkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMVpKZWlScGNmWGtkRnZ3OFZOQWRDOGhVZWZ6WlNEN0dMYlVOZzFxc0NhVVU9BjsARg%3D%3D--51d21b9b6c039eacece832c8fc17c221393a86b2; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Request-Id: 002d2081c7b55c3edf7070316a216c28
X-Runtime: 0.016595
X-Rack-Cache: stale, invalid
Content-Length: 8302
Accept-Ranges: bytes
**X-Varnish: 1359484771**
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish

lsoave@ubuntu:~/rails/github/gitwatcher$

Nobody still respond to my **Request #53071**, from Heroku support. Things just works ... If you have any idea about this delay or happened to you too, please post your experience.

> UPDATE: My last two answers fror Heroku/support:
>
> **May 31, 2012 15:09** We recently upgraded our varnish version and are currently investigating the effect this has had on cache purge
>   operations. To answer your question though, no, there is no way to
>   manually purge an item from the cache. Our system is designed to flush
>   all resources for your app's domains upon deploys.
>
> **1:02 AM (23 hours ago)** We haven't heard back from you in a while, so we're marking this ticket resolved. If you have further comments,
>   please feel free to reopen the ticket at
>   http://support.heroku.com/tickets/53071. Otherwise, feel free to open
>   a new issue here` http://support.heroku.com/tickets/new.